# ¿Como obtener datos de tabla roles las vistas a traves de los metodos de Auth en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo esta relación:

En User.php:

```
    public function roles()
{
    return $this
    ->belongsToMany('App\Role')
    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

en Role.php

```
public function users(){
return $this
    ->belongsToMany('App\User')
    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Estan relacionada mediante la tabla role_user:

```
public function up()
{
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
});
}
```

Estoy utilizando los metodos basicos de laravel que da Auth para autenticar, registrar, desloguear, me permite hacer todo bien hasta obtengo el nombre del usuario en la vista de de la siguiente manera:

```
{{ Auth::user()->nombre }}
```

Ahora mi pregunta es, como obtengo los datos de la tabla roles a traves de la relación con el metodo Auth en la vista? Estoy intentando algo asi, pero no funciona:

```
{{ Auth::user()->roles()->nombre }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener los roles tienes que acceder a la propiedad roles

```
{{ Auth::user()->roles }}
```

La función `->roles()` devuelve la relación mientras que la propiedad roles `->roles` devuelve los datos.

Como la relación de usuario - roles es 1 a n, esto te devolverá una colección de roles.

Tendrás que recorrer la colección para pintar todos los roles.

```
@php $roles = Auth::user()->roles @endphp
@foreach($roles as $rol)
    {{ $rol->nombre }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: gracias @Pepote, asi mismo es! Ya lo solucione